# Floating point performance on Raspberry Pi (ARM archetecture, BCM2835)

Tags: c++, c, performance, floating-point, raspberry-pi

From reading other questions about floating-point performance on modern desktop processors, it is my understanding that the answer to the question "Which is faster, double or float?" is dependent on which of these types is implemented in hardware, or in the CPU's ALU (Arithmatic Logic Unit, I think).

My understanding is that if float is implemented in hardware, then using double data types is slower because math using that data type is implemented through software using the float data type. Therefore double is slower and uses more ram.

On the other hand, if double is implemented in hardware, it is my understanding that a conversion (sort of like a truncation) must be done to convert to float data types. Hence using float will be slower, although it will use less ram.

On the Raspberry-Pi, which data type is implemented in hardware? (Equivalently, which is faster, float or double?)

I tried reading the limited parts of the datasheets for the BCM2835, but I didn't find the information I was searching for.

I should explain that I couldn't think of a good method of testing the performance, and so I didn't run any timed tests. By good method I mean one that assessed all possible calculations, or at least the calculations which I should test, and a test that would give consistent results, with enough difference that it could be concluded with reasonable certainty that one data type is faster than the other.

Comment: @EJP Oh right they're both implemented? I think the GPU can only handle floats, is that correct? In which case, which is faster? (on the CPU) Float because more floats may be sent though the data bus each cycle?

Comment: According to this http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture the ARM hw supports both single and double precision

Comment: @harmic Thanks for this, my guess is float may be faster then, if it were possible to transfer multiple value at once for use in a calculation? (For example, summing values in an array, or computing the power in a fourier spectrum, which is summing squares.)

Comment: @ejp “The FPU in Cortex-M4 supports single precision FP operations, but not double precision.” http://community.arm.com/docs/DOC-7544 Note that this quote is from arm.com, and the question here is tagged raspberry-pi. Apologies to the OP would not be out of place.

Comment: Raspberry Pi hardware supports both single and double precision floating point operations. [The CPU datasheet](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0301h/DDI0301H_arm1176jzfs_r0p7_trm.pdf) says so. See especially paragraph 1.5.9 for a description of vector floating point unit. Note that some versions of Raspbian do not use the floating-point hardware.

Comment: single and double, if you want to know which is faster for your application you simply need to run some benchmarks.  There is no universal answer, the answer is almost always "it depends"...

Comment: @dwelch Okay I'll try doing some, I suspect I won't get any definite results.

Comment: If there isnt a major difference then you are doing some pre-optimization that you can probably avoid...

Comment: @dwelch There is almost no difference. I ran 2 identical tests with different data types float and double. Any ideas why?

Comment: perhaps because there is no difference.  Should there be?

Comment: @dwelch I was told to expect a difference. I would have though so, yes.

Comment: Stephen's answer indicates there isnt a difference, your timing so far indicates there isnt a difference, empirically there doesnt have to be a difference, depends on the busses and architecture.  This is likely 64 bit data busses, and if the processor doesnt have a performance difference between single and double, then you shouldnt see a difference.   Make a simple test, disssemble it and post both and how you are timing it and perhaps we can explain why you are seeing what you are seeing or why you are not seeing a difference.

Comment: @dwelch This can't get very much more simple I'm afraid. In order to get the resolution required to assess a significant difference, the summation must be run many times, as shown in the example code. I agree a loop could probably be removed however.

Comment: @EdwardBird: “I was told to expect a difference” isn’t terribly compelling.  Did they give you a *reason* to expect a difference?  If your data is on the cusp of fitting in cache, there will be a difference due to the smaller memory footprint of floats.  If your data needs to stream from memory, there may be a difference for the same reason.  If your computation is throughput bound and involves multiplication, you will see a difference.  Otherwise, they should be quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi uses an ARM1176JZF-S(*) as its CPU, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), which has hardware support for pipelined single- and double-precision floating point.  You can look up the exact latency and throughput data in the [TRM on ARM's website](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0301h/Cegbeedf.html).  Short version: the latency is comparable for single and double; double-precision multiplies have half the throughput of single-precision.

Note that floating-point is only supported in arm mode on the 1176; the "thumb 1" instruction set does not allow access to the floating-point registers at all.

(*) The 1176 is *ancient*. I'm slightly surprised to not find something a bit more modern like an A9 or an M4.

Comment: I think they chose to use the ARM1176JZFS to cut costs (I remember reading something more in-depth in the past [but this is best source I could find](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#generalArm11)).

Comment: there is a cost for a chip vendor to switch cores, why change if you dont need to?

Comment: @dwelch: there’s also a cost to all the programmers who learn to tinker on something so out-of-date, doubled by the fact that RPi is often plugged to people who want to learn ARM assembly.  Having armv7 with Thumb2 and NEON would be significantly more useful for many of them.  Obviously, it’s a nontrivial tradeoff, and I wouldn't expect RPi to be bleeding edge (that’s why I was only *slightly* surprised =).

Comment: I wouldnt go that far, a very very very small percentage of the arm based products out there are even arm11 much less what you are talking about.  For what you are talking about use a beaglebone not a raspberry pi, for basic arm stuff a raspberry pi or beaglebone is fine (or a long list of others)